# What are the governor limits for the SandboxPostCopy Interface?

Tags: governorlimits, sandbox

What are the governor limits for SandboxPostCopy Interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SandboxPostCopy Interface provides the implementation to execute a class post refresh. So, I believe that SandboxPostCopy Interface will have the same governor limits which are applied to Standard Synchronous execution in Apex.

I do not have an official documentation for this but according to me it is just like a scheduler scheduled to run once after sandbox refresh.

Comment: Ok so would need to push it out to batch Apex for largen datasets?